# Send commands to other command-line programs

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, send

Is there a way, to send commands to another command-line program?

'Cause i have a special command-line program, but I can't send commands to it using syntax like `program.exe something_to_do`

the program executes something like this: ("here syntax" is where i want to input text to and also enter to start)

```
TheWhateverCommandLineProgram
Version 1.1
Give an option: "here syntax"
```

the program in code looks something like this:

```
echo TheWhateverCommandLineProgram
echo Version 1.1
Set opt=
set /p opt=Give an option: 
if %opt%==command1 goto com1
if %opt%==command2 goto com2
...
```

Well, i guess so cause it wasnt me who made it (btw: off course its not called TheWhateverCommandLineProgram)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the problem is.  Say a bit more about what your "special command-line program" is and what it is that you want to do.  Do you want to send commands to an already running program or just start it with a particular set of options?

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to give keyboard input to a commandline program you can just use `echo` and pipe it:

```
echo some text | program.exe
```

If you need more lines, then write them to a file and use input redirection:

```
echo one line > file
echo second line >> file
program.exe < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're looking for. Here's two options:

1. You have two windows, each running a batch program. Let's say they are called `myscript1.bat` and `myscript2.bat`. You want to send a set of commands from `myscript1.bat` to be executed by `myscript2.bat`
2. You have a single batch script named `myscript.bat`, which executes a single program named `program.exe`. You want `program.exe` to execute some commands, or do some something.

Are either of these what you're looking for? Here's some idea:

1. Make `myscript1.bat` create a third file, `mycommands.bat`. Once `myscript2.bat` sees the file `mycommands.bat` exists, it will execute it and delete it. (Wow. Lame.)
2. Use Windows Scripting Host command (it's built in to Windows since Win2K) or Powershell (usually on most computers nowadays, if they have been updated). Either of these can send keystrokes to another program. Using those keystrokes, you can control the other program.

Comment: I think the name of the function is `SendKeys`, but I can't remember which object you need. Googling for "sendkeys" gets you to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx - see the examples at the end of that page.

Comment: um, the problem is, it isnt available on Vista (so also on 7?) and this should be released to the public so...

Answer (score 0):

In what form does the other program take input? From the command prompt?

If the latter then I recommend Autohotkey: http://www.autohotkey.com/

You can use Autohotkey as a bridge and it will send the command as keypresses to the window of the other batch file.

You can ask for help in their forum. They are quite helpful.

Comment: but it doesnt have a commmand-line version :( i dont want that the user have to type those commands in :s

Comment: The user won't have to type the commands. Autohotkey will do the typing. Read its tutorial.

Comment: In particular you need the Send command: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm